# Hide and display select option based on other select value

Tags: javascript

I have this form with a few select dropdowns and based on what we select, we display and hide other dropdowns. When I select the value `All` then the `geo` select reacts to the selected value, but when I select the value `Test` the `function family` select doesn't disappear. Any reason why?

I also need to assign the value of the `function family` to `0` when the Test is selected. Help would be appreciated.

The main select:

```
<select name="scope" onchange="javascript:sync_scope()">
                            <option value="1">All </option>
                            <option value="10">Test</option>
                        </select>
```

Javascript:

```
 function sync_scope() {
      var scope = document.form.scope.value;
      document.form.geo.style.display = ( scope == "1" ) ? "block" : "none";     
      document.form.function_family.style.display = ( scope == "10" ) ? "none" : "block";

    }
```

The HTML

```
 <select name="geo">
    <?php foreach ($geos as $geo) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $geo['id']; ?>"><?php echo utf8_encode($geo['name']); ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>

<select name="function_family" id ="function_family">
<option value="0" <?php selected($function_family, 0); ?>>All functions</option>
<?php foreach ($functions as $function) : ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $function['id']; ?>"><?php echo utf8_encode($function['name']); ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: `onSomeEvent="javascript:doSomething()"` is redundant. `javascript:` is used in `<a href="...">` to indicate that the `href` is JavaScript code to be run, but inside an event handler you are already running JavaScript. The only reason it doesn't cause an error is because `javascript:` is treated as a Label, which is valid syntax.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol thank you for your feedback, even if i remove the javascript: it still doesn't hide the select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if condition is wrong in the second option:

```
 function sync_scope() {
      var scope = document.form.scope.value;
      document.form.geo.style.display = ( scope == "1" ) ? "block" : "none";     
      document.form.function_family.style.display = ( scope == "10" ) ? "none" : "block";

    }
```

should be:

```
 function sync_scope() {
      var scope = document.form.scope.value;
      document.form.geo.style.display = ( scope == "1" ) ? "block" : "none";     
      document.form.function_family.style.display = ( scope == "10" ) ? "block" : "none";

    }
```

To also apply the logic to select a specific value just do:

```
document.form.function_family.value = 0;
```

when scope equals 10. To add this you'd better write the if explicitly instead of using the ternary operator: this way you check once the value of scope and you apply all the logic you want at the same time

Comment: You were doing great, up until you said you need to "reset both to `none`" - that's exactly what the `: "none";` bit does in the conditionals.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol you are right... my bad. Will fix the answer :-)

Comment: Hi there, thank you, but still, the function_family doesn't react at all

Comment: Hey there, It's working fine now, but can you help me to set the value of the function_family to 0 when the Test is selected?

Comment: Thank you for helping me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="Audi">Audi
    <option value="BMW">BMW
</select>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var scope = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
        if (scope == "Audi") {
            document.getElementById("geo").style.display = "block";     
            document.getElementById("function_family").style.display = "none";
        } else if (scope == "BMW") {
            document.getElementById("geo").style.display = "none";     
            document.getElementById("function_family").style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>

<select id="geo">
    <option value="1">1
    <option value="2">2
</select>
<select id="function_family">
    <option value="3">3
    <option value="4">4
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, it's quite useful. I'm sorry but I had to accept the answer above.

Comment: No problem. Cheers. You may upvote my answer instead ;)